# foreach() to save several plots to disk in parallel

Tags: r, ggplot2, foreach, parallel-processing

I try to find out if parallelisation could speed up writing plots to disk. For this, I need of course to come up with working code for parallel plotting. This is what I tried:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(ggplot2)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

data(diamonds)

cuts <- unique(diamonds$cut)

foreach(i=1:length(cuts), .packages = "ggplot2") %dopar% {
  ggplot(filter(diamonds, cut == cuts[i])) +
    geom_line(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle(cuts[i])
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, ".png"))
}
```

Code above works fine for `%do%`, but not for `%dopar%`, where I run into the following error:

`Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types"`

Any hints what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `filter` is supposed to be the `filter` from `dplyr`.  Your current call of `filter` is calling `stats::filter()` (you can prove that you get the same error by running: `stats::filter(diamonds, cut == cuts[1])`)

You probably have `dplyr` on your `search()` path when you run the code with `%do%` however you'll need to export it in the `.packages` argument if you want to use it in the `%dopar%` (ie: `.packages = c("ggplot2","dplyr")`).

new `foreach` call:

```
foreach(i=1:length(cuts), .packages = c("ggplot2","dplyr")) %do% {
  ggplot(filter(diamonds, cut == cuts[i])) +
    geom_line(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle(cuts[i])
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, ".png"))
}
```

Comment: @adam-spannbauer I've tried your method but the `foreach()` loop never ends. I'm using Rstudio with R on Mac OSX. Any further insights why it's not working?

Comment: @SeanM the code posted here shouldn't have any problems getting stuck in an infinite loop.  it is likely a different issue somewhere else in your code. you could try opening a new question with a minimal repro example